# Display facebook.com in browser adress bar but display another site content in body

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to display example: https://www.facebook.com in my members browser adress bar but display another site content in my webpage body.. 
I want use .htaccess file. Help me.

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.facebook.com$ [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php [R=301,L]`

Not work.

Comment: Purely out of interest... why?

Comment: Cross post: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104307/display-facebook-com-in-browser-adress-bar-but-display-another-site-content-in-b